# r.js: Understand requirejs's r.js optimizer

Tags: requirejs, r.js

im trying to figure out if its a good idea to use r.js from require.js to generate a build.js file out of my javascript files to only load one file on production.
But im wondering if this is a good idea in my case as it seems its simply loading absolutely everything into the DOM using up a lot of memory. Maybe i got it wrong.

Look at one of my backbone based views i implemented using require.js. As i know, r.js will take this file and optimize and put it into the final build.js file with all the others views, models and collections defined the same way.

```
define(function (require) {
  "use strict";

  var $                   = require('jquery'),
      _                   = require('underscore'),
      Backbone            = require('backbone'),
      tpl                 = require('text!tpl/start.html'),
      Mustache            = require('mustache'),
      template            = Mustache.compile(tpl);

  return Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function () {
    },

    render: function () {
      this.$el.html(template());
      return this;
    },

    events: {
      'click #submit': "start"
    },

    start: function (event) {
       // stuff to do ...
    }
  });
});
```

I guess the final build.js will simply take my code above and concat them into it, right?
So this means when i update my index.html loading require.js then my build.js file, it will simply load all the views, models and collections into the DOM. Doesn't take that up too much memory, since i don't need everything to be loaded from the beginning.
Does it make sense to call require('path/to/my/view') when its loaded already via the build.js file?

Comment: By default (unless you set `findNestedDependencies` to true) r.js only includes modules that would be `require`d on startup anyway. The only difference would be that these resources would be loaded in a single HTTP request, as opposed to one request per module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might indeed not make sense for your application to optimize all modules into one single file. `r.js` supports this kind of scenario. What you have to do is use the `modules` option and define as many output files as you need. A generic illustration of this could be:

```
modules: [
    {
        name: 'main', 
        exclude: [ "viewA", "viewB" ],
    },
    {
        name: 'viewA',
        exclude: ['core']
    },
    {
        name: 'viewB',
        exclude: ['core']
    }
]
```

The setup above assumes that the source to be optimized has modules named `main`, `viewA` and `viewB`. It would create 3 optimized bundles: a `core` that contains all core modules that would be loaded *in any case*, `viewA` which represents a group of modules to be loaded in circumstances so and so, and `viewB` which represents a group of modules to be loaded in other circumstances.

How you should setup your `modules` parameter depends on the specifics of your application.

Comment: didn't know about that one. that gives me more "power" of how to get my file optimized. thanks.